# Código para calcular equação de 2º grau retorna "NaN" como raízes

Tags: java, lógica

Tentei criar um programa que calcula as duas raízes de uma equação de segundo grau. Quando executo meu código, ele pede os valores de `a`, `b` e `c` corretamente, mas na hora de mostrar o resultado, ele sempre retorna "NaN".

Meu código é este, não sei como resolver:

```
package com.Class1;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Class1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Insira o valor de a:");
        int a = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Insira o valor de b:");
        int b = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Insira o valor de c:");
        int c = in.nextInt();

        double pB = Math.pow(b, 2);
        double delta = pB - 4 * a * c;
        double x1 = -1 * pB + Math.sqrt(delta) / 2 * a;
        double x2 = -1 * pB - Math.sqrt(delta) / 2 * a;

        double r1 = Math.round(x1);
        double r2 = Math.round(x2);

        System.out.println("A raíz x1 vale: "+ x1);
        System.out.println("A raíz x2 vale: "+ x2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Basicamente é pelo fato de você estar tentando calcular a raiz de número negativo. Dependendo dos valores, delta será menor que zero, e o sqrt vai dar NaN

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você não está considerando o discriminante negativo (raízes complexas) no seu código.

Quando o valor do discriminante (`delta`) é negativo (e isto é comum em uma equação quadrática), a função `Math.sqrt` retorna `NaN`, que significa "Not a number". O `Nan` é propagado pelo resto da expressão, sendo armazenado em `x1` e `x2`.

Como na equação quadrática você pode ter raízes complexas no resultado, uma solução bem simples é você trabalhar normalmente com os valores positivos, e "avisar" na saída que se tratam de raízes complexas quando for o caso.

Dá para fazer isso de maneira bem simples com uma pequena adaptação no seu código:

```
    double pB = Math.pow(b, 2);
    double delta = pB - 4 * a * c;
    double x1 = -1 * pB + Math.sqrt(Math.abs(delta)) / 2 * a;
    double x2 = -1 * pB - Math.sqrt(Math.abs(delta)) / 2 * a;

    double r1 = Math.round(x1);
    double r2 = Math.round(x2);

    if(delta < 0) {
        System.out.println("A raíz x1 vale: "+ x1 + "i");
        System.out.println("A raíz x2 vale: "+ x2 + "i");
    } else {
        System.out.println("A raíz x1 vale: "+ x1);
        System.out.println("A raíz x2 vale: "+ x2);
    }
```

Basicamente acrescentamos o `Math.abs` aqui:

```
    double x1 = -1 * pB + Math.sqrt(Math.abs(delta)) / 2 * a;
```

O `Math.abs` retorna o valor absoluto, que na pratica vai retornar o número sempre positivo.

Para isto, usamos o `if(delta < 0)` para acrescentar o `i` na saída o `println`, pois neste caso, se tratam de raízes complexas, e não de raízes reais. Fundamental entender que `9` e `9i` são coisas completamente diferentes (mas aí o problema é de Matemática).

**Nota:** no seu código original, você está armazenando o `round` em `r1` e `r2`, mas não está usando o valor em lugar nenhum. Se for o caso de mostrar na tela os valores arredondados, ajuste as linhas de saída:

```
System.out.println("A raíz x1 vale: "+ r1); // troque o x por r em todas
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ljbwGQ)**.

Se quiser melhorar seu código, pode criar uma situação para mostrar uma raiz só quando for o caso do discriminante zero.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, realmente não estava considerando a probabilidade de números negativos. Meu upvote pra vc :)