# Equação de segundo grau

Tags: java

provavelmente está é uma duvida que já responderam por demais aqui, mas claro, não achei a solução. A única coisa que preciso é levar o cálculo que fiz no main para uma outra classe, retornando para o main apenas o resultado.

- Fiz algumas tentativas e o que consegui foi um retorno NaN.
  vale ressaltar que ainda sou novaço em java (alias, em todas as linguagens kkkk)
- Tenho uma segunda classe onde coloco os metodos, mas queria que existisse uma terceira. Ficaria então o main, apenas colhendo e retornando os valores, a classe Dados, armazenando os dados, e por fim a **formulas** que realizariam os cálculos.

segue o que tenho até agora:

```
package atividade;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner num = new Scanner (System.in);

        Dados f = new Dados();
        System.out.print("Informe os valores abaixo:\n"
                + "A: ");
        f.setA(num.nextDouble());
        System.out.print("B: " );
        f.setB(num.nextDouble());
        System.out.print("C: ");
        f.setC(num.nextDouble());
        System.out.println("\nValores informados: \nA: " + f.getA() +"\nB: " + f.getB() + "\nC: " + f.getC());
        double delta, x1, x2;
        delta = f.getB()*f.getB()-4*f.getA()*f.getC();
        x1 = (f.getB()+ Math.sqrt(delta))/(2*f.getA());
        x2 = (f.getB()- Math.sqrt(delta))/(2*f.getA());
        System.out.println("S={" + x1 + ", " + x2 + "}");
    }    
}
```

```
package atividade;

public class Dados {
    private double a;
    private double b;
    private double c;    

        public double getA() {
        return a;
    }
        public void setA(double a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
        public double getB() {
        return b;
    }
        public void setB(double b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
        public double getC() {
        return c;
    }
        public void setC(double c) {
        this.c = c;
    }          
}
```

Comment: Ao invés de inicializar os atributos da classe Dados com setters, você deveria fazer isso com um construtor. E qual a responsabilidade da classe Dados? Guardar os dados de uma expressão quadrática? Então, ela deveria se chamar Expressao e ela própria deveria calcular as suas raízes.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Código para calcular equação de 2º grau retorna "NaN" como raízes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164823/c%c3%b3digo-para-calcular-equa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-2%c2%ba-grau-retorna-nan-como-ra%c3%adzes)

Comment: Opa @VanderSantos, vou seguir essa dica então.

Comment: @MarcosAlexandre ajudou sim! vlw!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, uma pessoa teve o erro parecido com o seu, a resolução está aqui: [Código para calcular equação de 2º grau retorna "NaN" como raízes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164823/c%C3%B3digo-para-calcular-equa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-2%C2%BA-grau-retorna-nan-como-ra%C3%ADzes)